# Display rupee symbol via strings xml not working

Tags: android, currency

I using the following string entry in strings.xml file to display rupee symbol.

```
<string name="current_amount">"Balance: &#x20B9;%.2f"</string>
```

It displays a square rather than the actual symbol on Android 2.2.

Please help.

PS: I am testing it on an emulator for Android 2.2, I don't have a 2.2 device.

Comment: Have you installed a font containing that symbol?  What locale is the emulator set to?

Comment: I haven't installed a font. The locale is set to US.

Comment: Sorry, I have installed Roboto_Light.ttf font and have Custom Text View to display text in my application.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**[EDIT] Working soultion for Android 2.2**

Ok here's how you can get it to work. You'll have to download the font `Rupee_Foradian.ttf` from [here](http://www.karunadu.gov.in/pages/download-rupee-instructions.html) and put it in the `assets` folder.

Then, place this line in `strings.xml` file

```
<string name="rs">`</string>
```

And finally set the Typeface using this code:

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Rupee_Foradian.ttf");
t.setTypeface(face);
t.setText("Balance " + getResources().getString(R.string.rs));
```

[image]

---

**[Original] Doesn't work on Android 2.2**

Put this line in your strings.xml file

```
<string name="rs">\u20B9</string>
```

In your code, for example, if you're assigning it to a TextView do this:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("Balance " + getResources().getString(R.string.rs) + VALUE);
```

Comment: What's difference between "\u20B9" and "&#x20B9;"? Can you please explain?

Comment: No difference. Works the same. I thought the alternative might work.

Comment: I am testing on emulator running 2.2. Tested what you suggested but didn't work. And on emulators for 4.2, 4.3, etc, what I have is working.

Comment: @singh.jagmohan Please check my edit. I've edited my answer with a working solution. Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: try using RupeeTextView https://gist.github.com/john1jan/a82912fb355771e565bea1720439c5dc . It prefixes rupee symbol and adds even give comma separated amount

Answer (score 3):

```
<string name="current_amount">Balance: &#x20B9;</string>
```

I have tried this and it works

Comment: This is correct solution worked for me, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you are using a font that can display this unicode character.
You can change the font of your views as follows:

In your main activity **MainActivity.java**

```
public static final String PREF_MYFONT = "DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf";
```

In your view where you need to display the Rupee symbol **MyView.java**

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    myTitle=(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.title);
    myDescription=(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.description);

    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), MainActivity.PREF_MYFONT);  

    myTitle.setTypeface(font);
    myDescription.setTypeface(font);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pendingApprovalReceiptPaymentFragmentBinding.tvAmountValue.setText`(getResources().getString(R.string.Rs)+" "+Integer.toString(pendingApprovalListModel.getAmount()));`